# Append to a file with sudo

Tags: sudo, io-redirection, cat

I have a file named `foo` whose permissions are `-rwxr-x--- root` and I'm neither the user (root) nor in the group. I have another file named `bar`, which I want to append to `foo`. I've tried

`sudo cat bar >> foo`

but this fails with `foo: Permission denied`.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain please?

Comment: Yes, downvoters why????

Answer (score 6):

```
cat bar | sudo tee -a foo > /dev/null
```

[man tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee):

> -a, --append
>
> append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite

Here, we use tee as sudo in order to append to foo, and dump (to /dev/null) the other effect of tee: duplicating the input to the stdout.

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you explain why the original sudo fails?

Comment: It fails because sudo applies only to cat.

Comment: can also do `sudo tee -a /foo <bar >/dev/null`

Comment: Related: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2002 (*Useless cat. Consider `cmd < file | ..` or `cmd file | ..` instead*...)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve that would be this:

```
sudo bash -c "cat bar >> foo"
```